# Find overlapping ranges from a large set of data efficiently

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

Is there an efficient algorithm for checking for overlaps between multiple bounded continuous ranges?

If we have a pair of tasks, each represented by a start time and an end time, a function such as the one below can detect clashes.

```python
# tasks are of the form (start_time, end_time)

def has_clash(task_1: tuple[float, float], task_2: tuple[float, float]) -> bool:
    """Check if a clash exists between two tasks."""
    return (task_2[1] > task_1[0]) and (task_2[0] < task_1[1])
```

To check multiple tasks, we would have to run the above test pairwise on the set of tasks, for an overall complexity of O(n^2), e.g.:

```python
def has_any_clash(tasks: list[tuple[float, float]]) -> bool:
    """Check if any tasks clash, return True if no clashes, false otherwise."""
    if len(tasks) < 2:
        return False
    clash = any(
        has_clash(task, other_task)
        for i, (task) in enumerate(tasks[1:])
        for other_task in tasks[:i]
    )
    return clash
```

Can this complexity be improved upon by e.g. sorting or some other mathematical magic?

Is there an algorithm that does this more efficiently?

Comment: That's not even *correct*, fails even the simplest cases like `has_any_clash([(0, 2), (1, 3)]`.

Comment: Right you are - corrected now.

Comment: Did you test it? It still returns `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the list by start time, then just compare the last end to the next start time of consecutive entries. The complexity for this is just O(nlogn) for sorting and O(n) for iterating the pairs.

```
def has_any_clash(tasks: list[tuple[float, float]]) -> bool:
    """Check if any tasks clash, return True if no clashes, false otherwise."""
    sorted_tasks = sorted(tasks)
    return any(a2 > b1 for (a1, a2), (b1, b2) in zip(sorted_tasks, sorted_tasks[1:]))

print(has_any_clash([]))  # False
print(has_any_clash([(0, 4)]))  # False
print(has_any_clash([(1, 5), (0, 4)]))  # True
print(has_any_clash([(5, 8), (0, 4), (6, 7)]))  # True
print(has_any_clash([(9, 10), (0, 4), (6, 7)]))  # False
```

If you want a list *which* tasks clash (those could be more that just the consecutive ones) that is a bit more involved, but not by much. In addition to the above:

- keep track of "running" tasks, using a `heap`, sorted by end-time
- iterate tasks sorted by start-time, in each iteration:

  - pop tasks from running heap while end-time is < current tasks's start time
  - all remaining tasks in running heap clash with current task
  - add current task to running heap